# Can a worksheet object be declared globally in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm refactoring a number of modules in an Excel 2003 workbook and the same set of worksheets are declared in each procedure in each module; I'd like to just declare them once globally.  I can set the worksheet name as a literal, e.g.:

```
Public Const xlwkGSModel = "gs_model" As String
```

And then in the procedure use:

```
...ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(xlwkGSModel).Cells(1,1)
```

But is there a way to declare the worksheet object so that the code in the procedure could be:

```
...xlwkGSModel.Cells(1,1)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

'1. Insert a module

'2. Declare worksheet public variable in the module as follows

```
Public xlwkGSModel As Worksheet
```

'3. Instantiate this public variable in the application load event

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

   Set xlwkGSModel = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("gs_model")

End Sub
```

'Now you can refer the gs_model worksheet with the xlwkGSModel variable

'For example

```
dim x as string

x = xlwkGSModel.Cells(1,1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could, but do you really want more global variables? Why not create (within a standard module) a public property ModelWorksheet, like this:

```
Public Property Get ModelWorksheet As Worksheet
    Const ModelWorksheetName As String = "gs_model"
    Set ModelWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ModelWorksheetName)
End Property
```

...then your code can do:

```
With ModelWorksheet
    .Cells(1,1).Value = "foo"
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
```

Note also that you can refer to any of the worksheets *in the current workbook* directly, so if there's a sheet called Sheet1 you can do:

```
With Sheet1
    .Cells(1,1).Value = "foo"
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
```

Comment: Thinking about this... I don't know if I would recommend it. The problem with a property is that it looks like an object and if you're in a loop that updates, say, 15000 cells one by one, this is a lot of additional indirection to go through on each cycle. I think it would be better to use an Worksheet reference directly but YMMV. I still think it's better to go Dim sht as Worksheet / Set sht = ModelWorksheet() / sht.Cells(1,1)... and put the sheet grab into a ModelWorksheet function. I know it doesn't reduce the number of lines involved but going global is usually ill-advised.

Comment: @goodgai: agreed wholeheartedly; that actually is why I used a With statement, to avoid referencing the property twice, but I should have been more explicit. And you're right about even this method being not much help in a loop (unless the With ... End With wraps the entire loop).

Comment: Yes I did notice the Withs in your answer and saw what you were doing but I ran out of characters in my comment =) I worked out what I was trying to say now, concisely: defensive programming - by avoiding the property you're less likely to walk into a performance ambush by accident.

Answer (score 5):

It's a long time ago, but better late than never ;-)
I don't know if that works in Excel 2003 (tested it with 2007):

You don't even need to declare worksheets in the code, because they are already declared. I'm working with a German version of Excel and I can access a worksheet by typing "Tabelle1.Cells(...) ...". I assume in the English version it is something like "Table1" or "Sheet1".

You can also change these names. In the Visual Basic Editor have a look at the Microsoft Excel Objects of your VBA-Project. (They are right above your Modules and UserForms in the VBA-Project view). There are the Worksheet-Objects of your workbook. Select a sheet and activate the Properties Toolwindow. There you can edit the name of the sheet and access it by that name in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you do not want to use the Excel Event, you can also declare your worksheet publicly, then create a sub to set value for it. Call that sub at the beginning of each sub to initialize the value. (I did this from orwell's answer.)

---

```
Public WSRawData As Worksheet
```

---

```
Public Sub RawDataWSInit()

Set WSRawData = Worksheets(RawData)

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Main()

Call RawDataWSInit

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Your Worksheets are "Microsoft Excel Objects" defined in your VBA-Project-Explorer:

[image: Worksheet Properties editing]

In The Screen above i have named my Worksheet DataSheet, so now i can access it directly from within the code:

```
Set SomeRange = DataSheet.Range("A3:B6")
```

By Default your Worksheets will be named "Sheet1", "Sheet2", aso... depending on your language.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The comment by Alistair Knock is correct, I should have read the question thoroughly - of course my answer is not valid for objects, only for types like string or integer. For objects you need a function or sub that creates an instance.

---

Yes, you can, I recently did it. If you define your definitions as `Public` you can use them directly in your other modules (within the same workbook, of course).

Maybe the best approach is to have a seperate module *Globals* and put them there.

Comment: Presumably while the definitions can be made at module level, the values will need to be assigned in a procedure, e.g. in Workbook_Open()?  Since a constant can't contain objects...