# Excel 2010 VBA - global variables aren't set properly

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

UPDATE: 
I know I can just rename the sheets in VBA Editor, but my first instinct was to use code. I looked it up, saw the solution in several places, and now that it doesn't work I still want to know why.
The answer might mean I'll learn something critical for later programming in VBA.

---

I thought I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1179730/1370938, but it turns out that doesn't work for me, I don't know why. I'm new to VBA so I might be missing something, but I found this solution in multiple sites and I'm wondering if I missed a simple step that was not explicited.

I wanted to set global worksheet variables that I could call for all my functions and forms data manipulation and make the code look lighter. (all those `Worksheets("name").` really fatten up the code when you jump from sheet to sheet).

Following the answer in the link, I wrote this in one of my three modules:

```vba
'Global variables
Public shT As Worksheet
Public shA As Worksheet
Public shC As Worksheet
Public shM As Worksheet
Public shP As Worksheet

'Setting global variables
Sub Workbook_Open()

   Set shT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tasks")
   Set shA = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Activity")
   Set shC = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Closed")
   Set shM = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Modifications")
   Set shP = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Persistent")

End Sub
```

But When running this code in another module, the variable is set with "Empty" when trying to access ranges etc and I get runtime error '424' Object Required which points to the line `.Rows(3).EntireRow.Insert`.

Here is the code

```vba
Sub addModLogEntry(sTask As String, sOwner As String, dDate As Date, sType As String)
    Dim iRow As Integer
    With shM
        .Rows(3).EntireRow.Insert

        .Range("A" & 3).value = sTask
        .Range("B" & 3).value = sOwner
        .Range("C" & 3).value = dDate
        .Range("D" & 3).value = sType

        If Day(dDate) Mod 2 = 0 Then
             shM.Range("A" & 3 & ":D" & 3).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 230, 230)
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

When in debug mode if I watch the value of `shM` it returns `Empty`.
I tried putting a breakpoint on the first line of `Workbook_Open()` but the breakpoint isn't saved when I close the document to test opening it.

I tried puttin this code in the code for thisWorkbook and here the breakpoint works, workbook_open() is executed, but if I execute anything after it the variables are still no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dim** the variables in a Standard Module, not in the `ThisWorkbook` Module above the Open event code.

**EDIT#1**:

In the `ThisWorkbook` Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set shT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tasks")
   Set shA = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Activity")
   Set shC = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Closed")
   Set shM = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Modifications")
   Set shP = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Persistent")
End Sub
```

and in a standard module:

```
Public shT As Worksheet
Public shA As Worksheet
Public shC As Worksheet
Public shM As Worksheet
Public shP As Worksheet

Sub durAL()
    MsgBox shT.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

running durAL will demonstrate the globals are available for common use.

Comment: If you meant declare the variables in a module and keep the event in the workbook code then that worked. I didn't think they had to be in a separate space. Thanks!

Comment: If I open the document and execute code once it works fine. But when I get an error, enter Debug Mode, and stop the code to rerun after I make a modification, the variables aren't recognized any more. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, when you stop the code in the editor all global variables are terminated. They will not be re-initialised until after the WorkBook_Open event fires again.

Comment: also, you understand that the Workbook_Open sub must be located in the object called "ThisWorkbook" right?