# Global worksheet variable for userform in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a userform that adds data to a worksheet. I have a bunch of sub-routines for my userform, but I'm having issues accessing the variable I set to my worksheet. It's currently a local variable (in a sub) and have tried placing it in a module as discussed here: [Can a worksheet object be declared globally in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176743/can-a-worksheet-object-be-declared-globally-in-excel-vba). I've done some further searching but didn't quite get the results I wanted.

I'm quite new to VBA and new to programming in general. I've used Excel quite a bit and want to do more by creating macros and such using VBA. Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
sub savebutton_click()
    Dim trees As Worksheet
    Set trees = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    trees.Cells(1, 1) = Me.TextTreeName
    trees.Cells(1, 2) = Me.TextTreeType
End sub
```

Obviously I cannot access local variables from another subroutine, so I have to make 'trees' global. I created a module and replaced Dim with Public, placed the second line of code in Workbook_Open(), and then tried accessing the 'trees' variable. I get an "Invalid outside procedure" and highlights the code in Workbook_Open() when I hit 'Debug'.

Essentially I just want to be able to access, say, trees.Cells(5,6) from any sub and I'm not sure what else to do with it. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a matter of placement ... if you open the VBA IDE and select the ThisWorkbook item in your VBAProject. Double click that item to open it, Select Workbook in the top left dropdown, Select Open in the top right dropdown. This will create your Workbook_Open Sub in the ThisWorkbook object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set trees = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
End Sub
```

Right click your VBAProject and Add Module. In that module you put the global variable:

```
Public trees As Worksheet
```

Next you create your form, put the button on that and double click the button. This will generate the button event:

In my case:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     trees.Cells(1, 1) = Me.TextTreeName
     trees.Cells(1, 2) = Me.TextTreeType
End Sub
```

Now if you close the Excel Workbook (save the code and the workbook first) and reopen the Workbook the Workbook_Open() will kick in and set the Worksheet. Now call your Form, and click the button. This will fill the two cells on the given sheet....

Comment: Thanks for your response. What's weird is that I did everything you mentioned from scratch (created a test file), saved everything and ran the userbox BEFORE closing the entire file. I got an error. After closing the workbook and reopening it, I ran the code without any issues. To me, that just seems weird.

Anyway, if I understand correctly, all global variables go in the Workbook_Open() sub, correct? So if I were to set a variable mapleTree = trees.Cells(1, 9), I'd be able to access mapleTree from other subs? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Public variables can be declared in any module as well as in any worksheet code pane, and declaration statement MUST be placed outside at the top of it before the first Sub or Function occurrence. Once declared they're accessible from any Sub/Func of any module, both for setting and retrieving purposes. I'd add that if your variables must be shared only between Subs/Func all residing in the same Module, then it'd be a better choice declaring them as "module level" variable ( i.e. `Dim trees as Worksheet`) at the very top of the module itself.